# How to save a referance to callback of addEventListener and retrieve it in removeEventListener

Tags: javascript, events

I have an object contain many methods among them two methods, the first to add event to an element, and the other to remove that event.

```
event: function (event, callback, capture) {
    var _this = this;
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        var fn = function(){callback.call(_this);}
        this[0].addEventListener(event, fn, capture || false);
        this.eventFunc = fn;
    }
    return this;
},
remEvent: function (event) {
    if (document.removeEventListener) {
        this[0].removeEventListener(event, this.eventFunc);
    }
    return this;
}
```

When usage:

```
oo('#on_btn').event('click', function(){console.log("clicked")});
oo('#on_btn').remEvent('click');
```

In the previous code you seen that I use a public variable `this.eventFunc` to save a reference to the callback function. and then I have used it in `removeEventListener`. but the problem is that public variable is always `undefined` and thus the `removeEventListener` does not works fine.

**Now, how can I transfer the reference of callback to the** `removeEventListener` **function to remove the event that I have added before ?**

Comment: `_this.eventFunc` will be `undefined` until the event handler is called. You should set `_this.eventFunc` *outside* of the event handler, before or after you call `this[0].addEventListener`. However one problem still remains: `_this.eventFunc` will always reference the last bound event handler.

Comment: @FelixKling: So, if my way is not good, what is the best way to transfer the reference to the `removeEventListener ` in this case ?

Comment: You gave the callback a name (`fn`). You can remove it by name.

Comment: @RaymondChen: By name does not works because `fn` in a method and the other in another method ex: `this[0].removeEventListener(event, fn);`.

Comment: @FelixKling: I have done what you said `var fn = function({callback.call(_this);}; this[0].addEventListener(event, fn, capture || false); this.eventFunc = fn;` but unfortunately, it still does not prevent the event. and the event still works.

Comment: I don't know how `oo` works, but presumable it returns a *new* object whenever it is invoked? In that case, yeah, that won't work. You might want to have a look at the jQuery source code and see how they do it.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Missed that. Follow @FelixKling's advice. Note sure what you mean by "it still does not prevent the event". Are you saying that `remEvent` does not remove the event? Are you sure that `this[0]` has not changed?

Comment: @FelixKling: `oo` is a shortcut for main object, and as you said it returns a new object, like jQuery `$`.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Yes,  the event still worked, and it has not been removed.

Comment: Please share the code that doesn't work. Have you verified that `this[0]` is the same?

Comment: @RaymondChen: I do not want to share the fully code, because maybe will become big and thus will show the complexity, for that I have posted the important part only. also for `this[0]` is just an html element that I got it, and I can apply anything on it, like jQuery `$('#elementId')`.

Comment: You posted code in the question. Update that code to show the changes you made that you claim don't work. And you still haven't said whether you verified that `this[0]` is the same element when you call `addEventListener` as when you call `removeEventListener`. (Maybe something changed in the DOM, and `this[0]` corresponds to a different element when you get around to remove it.)

Comment: @RaymondChen: I have been updated the code to last changes that does not work also. concerning to matching the element `this[0]`,  the element is the same as, in two methods.

Comment: Is `this.eventFunc` still `undefined` after you assign it at the end of the `event` handler?

Comment: @RaymondChen: If I write this code `console.log(this.eventFunc);` inside the `event` method, I find it works and it gives me a reference to the callback, but when I write the same code inside the `remEvent` I find it still gives me `undefined`.

Comment: You answered in a comment to @FelixKling the `oo` function returns a new object each time it is called. Therefore, the `event` method and the `remEvent` method are called on different objects, so naturally they have different private variables.

Comment: @RaymondChen: thanks, but how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: You'll have to save it somewhere else. [You can see how jQuery does it](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js)